# Simplyscroll won't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, simplyscroll

I've tried to create some vertical scrolling using SimplyScroll on [this website](https://portal.gbnett.no/filarkiv/testing.html), but the images are ending up as a list.

Does somebody know why?

Comment: You're trying to load jQuery 1.8, which is 3.5 _years_ old... (As Dave said, just open your console, it will tell you what the problem is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Show us some code. Don't make us go and find it.

2 - Use your F12 console. [This works](http://portal.gbnett.no/filarkiv/testing.html).

You're trying to load jQuery over HTTP. You're loading your site over HTTPS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Omitting the schema from a `src` attribute will let the browser load it over the appropriate schema - http or https, depending on how the other content has been loaded. You should do the same for your images and scripts.

*Mixed Content: The page at 'https://portal.gbnett.no/filarkiv/testing.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

Comment: While you're at it, you could have suggested to use a more recent jQuery version. v1.8 is 3.5 _years_ old...

Comment: @Jeremy It's not for me to tell people which versions of which libraries to use. What if a user has paid out for a Bootstrap theme which relies on some of the [features that were deprecated in 1.8](https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)? Your comment doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer :) It could also be that OP is following an old tutorial, including a largely outdated version of jQuery. In that case, it would be a good advice to suggest an update.

Comment: @mapboxproblems No worries - hope it's resolved! Please consider [marking this as the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped!